# Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture (or the neutral culture) exception when using CreateFileBasedResourceManager

Tags: vb.net

In my win forms application, I have a Language Folder in which I have compiled the .resources file from a text file. But When I run the application I get the below exception

Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture (or the neutral culture) on disk. baseName: SpanishLanguageResource.es-ES  locationInfo:

My Code is:

```
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = New System.Globalization.CultureInfo(gLocale)
       rm = ResourceManager.CreateFileBasedResourceManager("SpanishLanguageResource.es-ES", ".", Nothing)
```

Can anyone Please guide me into the right direction What I am missing? Thanks

Comment: I added the resource file to the bin directory and it resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I added the .resource file to the bin directory and it resolved the issue.